# Android: Android App is not responding, close it?

Tags: android, error-handling

I have an application which sends data to a server and sometimes the following message appears: Android app is not responding , Close it? ( i don't know if is the same in English)

It's difficult to see the log because it happens in one of 20 devices approximately when they are all working, and I can't see the log at that moment.
I think the problem can be with the Asynctask function that sends data to the server.

Here is the function:

```
class UpdateCandidatos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Nombres.getPID()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", nombre));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pregunta", npregunta));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bateria", levelstring));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("correctas", correctasString));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("errores", fallosString));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update,
            "POST", params);

    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {

        } else {

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

When it is called the asynctask function:

```
bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    count++;
    if (radBotA.isChecked()) {
        Respuestas[posicion] = "A";
    }
    else if (radBotB.isChecked()) {
        Respuestas[posicion] = "B";
    }
    else if (radBotC.isChecked()) {
        Respuestas[posicion] = "C";
    }
    else if (radBotD.isChecked()) {
        Respuestas[posicion] = "D";
    }
    else {
        Respuestas[posicion] = "";
    }
    if (Titulacion.IsReachable1(getApplicationContext())) {
        Correccion();
        new UpdateCandidatos().execute();
    }
}
});
```

The message appears after there is some time that even you click on any button the app continues blocked. Is there anything wrong on my asynctask function? How Could I solve this problem?

Edit: Correccion() is comparing 2 arrays.

```
public void Correccion(){
                correctas = 0;
                fallos = 0;
                sinresponder  = 0;
        for(int posicion=0;posicion<=nPreguntas-1;posicion++){
if(Respuestas[posicion].equals(RespuestasC[posicion])){

    correctas++;
}
else if(Respuestas[posicion].equals("")){
    sinresponder++;
}
else{
    fallos++;
}
        }
        correccion++;
        correctasString = String.valueOf(correctas);
        fallosString = String.valueOf(fallos);
            }
```

isReachable() is used in order to know if the device can reach the Server.

```
public static boolean IsReachable1(Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo netInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isReachable = false;

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.0.15/");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               urlc.setConnectTimeout(1 * 200);
                urlc.connect();
                isReachable = (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return isReachable;
    }
```

Comment: which version of android are you testing?

Comment: Just a suggestion- try using testflight or crashlytics, to find more info about your application after your release

Comment: Application Not Responding is because the UI thread is blocked for 5 seconds or more. What's in `IsReachable1()` and `Correccion()`?

Comment: I've editted with these 2 methods. What can I do to avoid locking the UI thread for more than 5 seconds?

Comment: Updated my answer, move both functions call inside your async task!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click several times on the button you start several asyncTask, I suggest:

1. Avoid multiple task: wait for previous execution end
2. Use the following code to start the task:

The code:

```
myTask = new GetDeviceLogTask();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[]) null);
else
    myTask.execute((Void[]) null);
```

**EDIT:**

Ok I think you're doing to much things on the main thread that normally is used only to update the user interface and you may not use for caluclations. So try to move `Correccion()` and `.IsReachable1()` inside your async task:

```
class UpdateCandidatos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        if (!Titulacion.IsReachable1(getApplicationContext())) {
            return null;
        }

        Correccion();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Nombres.getPID()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", nombre));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pregunta", npregunta));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bateria", levelstring));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("correctas", correctasString));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("errores", fallosString));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update,
                "POST", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Seraphim, thanks for your help. I will test both solutions and I'll tell you if I solve it.

Comment: first, try the second solution: move function calls inside the asynctask!

Comment: Hi Seraphim, apparently it does the same task but more efficently. I will test on some devices and I will let you know the result. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, use AsyncTask wherever you need to do caluclations, network operations and other "cpu consuming tasks"!